# setProgressBackgroundTintList is not working in android

Tags: android, seekbar

I am trying to change the color of AppCompatSeekBar. I can change the color of progress color and thumb color. But setProgressBackgroundTintList is not working. please help me on this.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= MobeixUtils.LOLLIPOP) {
                if(progressColors!=-1)
                slider.setProgressTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(progressColors));
                if(progressBackgroundColors!=-1)
                slider.setProgressBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(progressBackgroundColors));
                if(thumbColors!=-1)
                slider.setThumbTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(thumbColors));
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Kindly change ColorStateList.valueOf to ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getActivity(),progressBackgroundColors)